# Whats the Java equivalent of NSArrays and arc4random?

Tags: java, objective-c, arraylist, nsarray

I'm current starting to port one of my apps to Android and stuck on a very basic bit, basically in my app I set an `NSArray` and then call:

```
int chosen = arc4random() % [array count];
textOutput.text = [array objectAtIndex: chosen];
```

but I can't seem to get this in Android.

All I need is to set the array manually and then to randomly select a string from it.

----- How I managed it -----

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array((new String("Blah, blah.")));
String randString = new String();
randString = array(new Random().nextInt(array()));  
textBox.setText(randString, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The java equivalent of an NSArray would be the java.util.List with its different implementations like e.g. java.util.ArrayList. (or more exactly, List is more like an equivalent of NSMutableArray, as Java does not really come with something like non-mutable lists).

To create a random number, you can use java.util.Random, like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(myList.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

Jut do something like

```
import java.util.Random;
// ...
textOutput.text = theArray[new Random().nextInt(theArray.length)];
```

Comment: If you need to do more than one, then save the `Random` object and use it multiple times.